# $ is not defined in mocha chai test script

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

i am trying to write a unit test case for a js function, its inside a .js file am loading that to a test.js file and then run

> npm test test.js

my test script contains

```
const app = require('../js/customJs/myjs.js');
var assert = require('chai').assert;
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
describe('Testing my test functions', function () {
     console.log("ready 2 test d dom");
     const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><p id="myid"></div>');
     it('check the return value of helloworld module', function () {
         assert.equal(dashboard_tab.helloworld(),"hello");
     });
});
```

'myjs.js' file has helloworld function which gets a value from a dom element and call an ajax call , 
so i am trying to unit test if the return value is "hello"('of course this test fails, since that function will not be returning hello'),but while running this test script i was getting error like '$ is not defined'

> myjs.js

```
var count = 0;
       function helloworld(){
          var id_Val = $("#myid").val();  //i was getting $ is not defined here when i run test.js
           $.ajax({
                url: "test/",
                data: { 'id': id_Val },
                dataType: 'json',
                   success: function (data) {
                    //some code
                  }
           });
       }
```

i tried

> global.$ = require('jquery')(window); // now, window is not defined

how to unit test a js function which includes jquery ($)

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by $ conflict

Please click [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) to know how to avoid it.

$conflict also occurs when you load jQuery file multiple times. Could you please check that also

Comment: thanks Ansar joseph, according to that link , var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); i have to alias all my jquery from '$' to '$j' , which can not be possible with my file (containing 4000 lines of code).

Comment: You can try this as well (function( $ ) {
    // Your jQuery code here, using the $
})( $j );